# Is there a way to make a div display "upwards" when it is going to be cut off by overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using Harvest Chosen for some dynamic select elements, but I'm running into a problem where if the select element is near the bottom of the page the select list gets cut off.  The containing div is set to overflow:hidden, and for some reason changing that to overflow:visible results in a scrollbar showing up inside the container div.

It would be really nice if I could just get the options list to behave like a normal dropdown, and render "upwards" when the bottom would get clipped.

So is there some magic css (or maybe javascript/jquery) that could force the div to show on top of the select element instead of below it, but only when it would be cut off by the containing element?

Or better yet an option in the Harvest Chosen plugin that I missed?

Comment: You'd need to create your own "magic" code to detect to adjust the position of the div

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing in CSS which will make an element push up it clips the border of its container

Answer (score 0):

Looks like even in chosen 1.2.0, it still has the same behavior.  I'm surprised nobody has added this feature yet.  The alternative: use Select2.